# Android: Make TableRow independet of TableLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here's my issue, I have a `TableLayout` that has multiple `TableRows`.

I want them in a table for making the right alignment, but I wanted that one of the `TableRow's` inside the `TableLayout` was independent of all of the sizes and was independent and the `TextView` inside was centered.

This is my code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.catarinaferreira.tripmanager.reservation_payment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_title_total"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="?attr/colorControlHighlight"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/laranja_logo"
        android:text="Pagamento"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView26"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="casual"
        android:text="Resumo Reserva"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/total_going_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/total_going_table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:showDividers="middle">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#f1f1f1"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView28"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="Qtd"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView29"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:text="Descrição"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView30"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="Preço(€)"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView31"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="Total(€)"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView32"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Ida"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView35"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView41"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Adulto"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView42"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="20€"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView43"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="20€"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then I show you images of my problem. I want the `TextView` in the `TableRow` with blue backgound to be centered like this:

[image]

But if the `TextView` has more characters, the "Qtd" column will be affected like this with a big space:

[image]

How can I do this for the size of the `TextView` text doesn't affect the first column?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change TableRow with this:

```
                 <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView32"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Regresso"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </TableRow>
```

Comment: @Catarina Ferreira, Let me know if it is helpful.

Comment: Yes it worked really well! I just toke time because this problem was programatically and I created this layout adapted to what I was doing in code. I adapted this new version to code version and now I don't have that problem anymore. Thanks!!